# Bloomberg API: Search for a company and return all associated tickers

Tags: bloomberg, ticker

I'm programming using the Bloomberg API. I need to be able to search for a company and get a list fo all tickers associated with that company. I'm working with .net version.

Can anyone please direct me to what sort of request I need to make?

Comment: Have you tried the `RELATED_EQUITIES` field?

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for the //blp/instruments service.
In the SDK this is documented as the SecurityLookupExample.

You can create an instrumentListRequest along the lines of:

```
InstrumentListRequest = {
    query = "IBM"
    yellowKeyFilter = YK_FILTER_NONE
    languageOverride = LANG_OVERRIDE_NONE
    maxResults = 10
}
```

This will return a list of instruments like "IBM US Equity", "DD103619 Corp", "IBM UN Equity", etc.